# Studio shows no log from iOS 10 device

Tags: ios, titanium, appcelerator-studio

Ever since installing iOS 10 beta on my iPhone I have been unable to see any logging in Studio Console when installing my app on my device.

Why is that and can it be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a JIRA ticket on the appcelerator JIRA instance that they recently closed as 'not our bug'.  They believe its been fixed with the GM release of xCode 8. If that is not the case, comment on the jira ticket.

https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-23786

I know that during the beta, iOS 10 devices were spewing worthless info into the console (not using titanium), so Apple did seem to have some things to work on.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the info. I did install the GM version of Xcode yesterday but am still not seeing anything in the console. Will look into it.